# elasticsearch Active: failed (Result: exit-code)

Tags: centos, elasticsearch

```
[root@66-226-73-146 elasticsearch]# sudo service elasticsearch restart
Restarting elasticsearch (via systemctl):                  [  OK  ]
[root@66-226-73-146 elasticsearch]# sudo service elasticsearch status
? elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-12-12 13:16:29 PST; 28s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 22572 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 22572 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 12 13:16:29 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com systemd[1]: Started El...
Dec 12 13:16:29 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com systemd[1]: Starting E...
Dec 12 13:16:29 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com elasticsearch[22572]: ...
Dec 12 13:16:29 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com systemd[1]: elasticsea...
Dec 12 13:16:29 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com systemd[1]: Unit elast...
Dec 12 13:16:29 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com systemd[1]: elasticsea...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Can someone please guide me how to fix this error?

here is server info

```
[root@66-226-73-146 elasticsearch]# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: 66-226-73-146.phx.dedicated.codero.com
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Machine ID: 082d95d159ce47ccb4b529d1e5e986bd
           Boot ID: eb3d64e59d834417924b915cb094f30b
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

> Linux version 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc
>   version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Apr 12 15:04:24 UTC 2017`

Comment: First, you should look at the log entries.

Comment: /var/log/elasticsearch is empty

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't install Java?

Elasticsearch quitely assumes that you have Java installed. If you make sure that `java` command is working on your system then you are likely to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming you followed [Install Elasticsearch with RPM | Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html#rpm), which Java 8 distribution did you install? Oracle or OpenJDK?
- To Configuring logging levels - [Logging configuration | Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html#configuring-logging-levels).
- As alternative, you can [Install Elasticsearch with Docker | Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)